# better way to handle multiple tables relationship

Tags: php, mysql, schema, cakephp-2.0, rdbms

Suppose i have some tables like...
**countries**

```
id name  
1  Cyprus  
2  India
```

**states**

```
id name country_id   
1   a     1   
2   b     2   
3   c     2
```

**cities**

```
id name state_id   
1   x     1     
2   y     2  
3   z     3  
4   p     2
```

**pages**

```
id name  slug    status   
1   ab   a-b       1      
2   pq   p-q       0   
3   abc  a-b-c     1
```

**mode_of_training**

```
id  name 
1   Virtual
2   Classroom
```

**items**

```
id name description 
1   a   something   
2   b   something
```

**prices**

```
id price currency_code 
1   200   USD
2   300   AUD
3   4000  INR
```

offers

```
id name   discount
1  xyz-1   20%
2  abc-2   30%
3  pqr-3   10%
```

Creating table structure in that way is correct?? so that i can reuse them
using there ids.

For example

**items_relation_table**

```
id country_id state_id  city_id  page_id item_id price_id offer_id  status
1   0           0         0       1        1       1         0        1
2   0           0         0       1        1       1         1        0
3   1           0         1       2        2       1         2        1
4   1           0         1       3        3       2         1        1
```

- Now i don't need to use field values of tables
- If i want to change price. i'll change price in one place only
- I'm saving number of bytes.
- database table size is less

But my problem is 
To fetch data i need to use Joins
Or Creating View is better idea
**Or There is any Better way to create table structure**

Comment: I think that, as you said, creating a view in this case is the best option.

Comment: This is not the correct way to create the database. You should learn something about E-R schemas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your entity-tables look fine at the first glance. But I don't understand your relation table. Looks like you try to relate everything with everything, which in some cases probably doesn't make sense (do offers really belong to countries?) in in some cases it seems redundant: When a page is linked to (many) cities, there is no need to link it to the countries too, because the countries are determined by the cities.

You should add relation-tables only between those entities that really need to be in a direct many-to-many relation. And for each of those relations you need a separate table.

e.g. for a relation between pages and cities:

```
cities(id, name, state_id) <--> cities_pages(city_id, page_id) <--> pages(id, name, slug, status)
```

And yes, you have to join tables to fetch data. Thats one of the basic ideas behind relational databases. Don't be afraid of joins, if your tables are properly indexed thats not an expensive operation at all (assuming that performance is your concern). And of course you could add some views if that makes sense for your application, but that will include the same JOINS you would just abstract them behind `CREATE VIEW` statements.

Comment: (do offers really belong to countries? yes

Comment: city page can have different content ,country page can have different content same for state ...

Comment: We can apply offer for one country

Comment: We can apply offer for country and state

Comment: We can apply offer for country state city

Comment: Ok if my boss said apply offer for a particular country,state,city,page,item,price how can i do that???